# Connecting 3 wireless routers together

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-bridge

I have 3 routers TP link TL-WR740N. I would like to build a single connection betweem these 3 routers. So any phone connected to the last router in the chain could access the bandwidth of all the networks.

Answer (score 1):

Router 1: 192.168.0.1 (static)
DHCP server: Enabled
DHCP Pool: 192.168.0.10-100
Subnet: 255.255.255.0

Router 2: 192.168.0.2 (static)
Gateway: 192.168.0.1
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
DHCP server: disabled

Router 3: 192.168.0.3 (static)
Gateway: 192.168.0.1
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
DHCP server: disabled

Connect all three using ethernet cables using the LAN sockets - never the WAN. The only WAN connected is router 1 to the ISP.

Comment: Can i do this wirelessly, connecting wires between them is not possible as they are in different floors of different buildings. I just want to avoid the extra cost that will follow the drilling and renovating the holes.

Comment: No because you would need to create a wireless bridge between the routers and then you would also need radio equipment to create your usable wireless network for clients. Or you would need to use a different firmware that might be capable of creating the bridge and access point using your existing equipment.

Comment: How far apart are the buildings? If each building has its own Internet connection that you have access to then you might be able to create a site-to-site VPN. Again, you will need equipment and/or firmware that supports this. SoHo equipment is not designed for this.

Comment: I researched about that. I havr come across a firmware patch that could create 2 SSIDs on a single router. So I have been thinking to use the extra SSID to create a bridge between the routers. Also will I get added speed of these routers or the final speed of the connection of the 3rd router.

Comment: The buildings are not far away. The main problem is the location of the routers. The are located deep, one in the basement of the godown and another 2 in the office in the next building.